# Memory requirements for WildFly

Tags: memory, jboss, webserver, wildfly, wildfly-8

I never found an official documentation about it and I generally install [WildFly](http://www.wildfly.org/) 8.x on servers with, at least, 4GB.

How much memory should my server have in order to run a WildFly instance?

Is there a minimum recommended?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The minimum value of Xmx is the one that let you start an empty instance of WildFly. On my try, it is **24 MB**. There is no other valid value for a minimal Xmx. 4g is a totally arbitrary value. It's absolutely depending on your application, on the number of user,...

You have to run a stress test on your application and measure the memory. It is the only way to know the minimum for *your* application.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer in my opinion! Thank you, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

That depends on  your application requirement.
In general I would recommend 4GB as a minimum. Note that you should have enough memory for the OS and it's caches.
Some small applications run perfect with <1GB for WildFly some need >32GB as they have lots of data.

So it's on you and you should test and measure it.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other answers I'd like to add a few points.

This would also depend upon :

1. Are you running the server in domain mode or standalone mode ?
2. Do you want all the components of the profile you are running the server with? If not you can create custom profile by removing unwanted components.
3. How many apps do you plan to deploy on the server ?
4. What is your performance/availability requirements ?
5. You need not always need 4GB ram, we run wildfly on our production servers with min memory set to 512MB and max as 1GB, till date no memory issues :)